# applying functions to objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

Excuse the beginner question, but I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around this. Using jquery I can do something like this:

```
$.each(array, testF); 

function testF(){
    console.log(this.name);  
}
```

Using $.each I can pass the array to the the function testF, and access the object contained within each row of the array. But when I try to do something like:

```
array[0].testF()
```

I get an error stating that the Object has no method 'testF'. I'm wondering if someone can explain what's happening here... why the jQuery one works, but the second doesn't. Again, please excuse the beginner question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `$.each(array, testF)` calls `testF(i, elem)` for each element in the array with `this` bound to `elem`.
- `array[0].testF()` tries to call a method `testF()` that exists on `array[0]`

The equivalent of what `$.each()` does is `testF.call(array[0], 0, array[0])` or since you do not use the arguments you can simpl do `testF.call(array[0])`

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for the documentation of [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: How does jQuery bond `this` to `testF`?

Comment: It uses [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call); a method every function in JavaScript has. Here's the statement copied from the jQuery source: `callback.call( object[ i ], i, object[ i++ ] )`

Answer (score 2):

Do it like so:

```
testF.call( array[0] );
```

The `call` function method enables you to set the context (the `this` value) of the function invocation. So, whenever you want to invoke a function with a custom context, instead of `fn();`, do `fn.call( context );`.

Answer (score 1):

this is because the object array[0] has no function testF,
You will need to declare that first.
like so:

```
array[0].testF = function testF()
{
    console.log(this.name);
}

array[0].testF();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `array[0].testF()`, this means:

- Look up the variable `array`
- Take the element under the index `"0"`
- Within *that*, take the element under the index `"testF"`
- and execute it as a function (also assigning the special variable `this` to `array[0]`)

However, in most circumstances, `array[0]` will not have an attribute `testF` defined. If you were to do this beforehand:

```
array[0].testF = testF;
```

then it would work.

Comment: I'd replace #3 with "Lookup the property "testF" of that element".

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Fair enough; even though arrays in JavaScripts are just special objects, with numeric property names so I meant to show the equivalence.

Comment: I appreciate the step-by-step explanation. Thanks.